# External File Access in Windows Server 2012

Tags: php, firebird, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a PHP system outside company which must access a firebird database at my intranet. While this database was at Windows 10 this PHP could access my database, but now I change database to Windows Server 2012, and fix all forwards ports to give external access, I can not access my database.

When I run `telnet ip port` from outside company, they capture my request, but when I run my PHP system, I can not.

error:

I/O error during "CreateFile (open)" operation for file "C:\USERS\ADMIN_REDE\DROPBOX\JFINANCAS\EMP-0007.JFIN" Error while trying to open file O sistema não pode encontrar o caminho especificado.

May anybody helps me?

Tks

Comment: Edit your question with details, don't use comments for that. And that error indicates that you can connect to the Firebird server, but the database either doesn't exist or the Firebird server does not have rights to access file in that location (and rightly som a service like a database server has no business  accessing files in the user-folder of an admin account).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel also not it is `DROPBOX` folder - one of the first online automatic background sync services (like SpiderOak, MS OneCloud/SkyDrive, Ya Disk, Google Drive and many many others). So it is quite plausible right when FIREBIRD tried to lock the database file that service opened and was slowly scanning it computing hashes and checking against central server history, looking whether it maybe should upload/download the file. Truly, they are asking for disaster....

Comment: @Arioch'The I hadn't even noticed the dropbox part, that is even worse and even a potential way for corrupting the database.

Answer (score 0):

You are able to connect to Firebird server, as the error shown is one created by the server. That error indicates that the database either doesn't exist or the Firebird server does not have rights to access files in that location. And in this case rightly so, a service like a database server has no business accessing files in the user-folder of an admin account.

Put the database somewhere where the user running the Firebird server service actually has read and write access. Also make sure that is not a shared location. Running a database from dropbox, like you are currently doing, is a bad idea, because it may lead to database corruption. If you want backups, then add a task to the task scheduler that creates a backup of the database (using gbak or nbackup) and put that backup on dropbox.